# How can I use proxies for web requests in Flurl?

Tags: c#, flurl

I have a simple post request using the Flurl client, and I was wondering how to make this request using a proxy using information like the IP, port, username, and password.

```
string result = await atc.Request(url)
    .WithHeader("Accept", "application/json")
    .WithHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    .WithHeader("Host", "www.website.com")
    .WithHeader("Origin", "http://www.website.com")
    .PostUrlEncodedAsync(new { st = colorID, s = sizeID, qty = 1 })
    .ReceiveString();
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was looking for a similar answer and found this:
https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/228

Here is a copy of the contents of that link. It worked for me!

> You can do this with a custom factory:
>
> ```
> using Flurl.Http.Configuration;
>
> public class ProxyHttpClientFactory : DefaultHttpClientFactory {
>     private string _address;
>
>     public ProxyHttpClientFactory(string address) {
>         _address = address;
>     }
>
>     public override HttpMessageHandler CreateMessageHandler() {
>         return new HttpClientHandler {
>             Proxy = new WebProxy(_address),
>             UseProxy = true
>         };
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> To register it globally on startup:
>
> ```
> FlurlHttp.Configure(settings => {
>     settings.HttpClientFactory = new ProxyHttpClientFactory("http://myproxyserver");
> });
> ```

Comment: Would this affect all clients? What if you need to use proxy for https://x.com/endpoint and use it without proxy for https://y.com/endpoint?

Comment: Yes it is a global Flurl setting so it would affect all connections. For mixing proxy and non: if Flurl doesn't support separate instances, you could try separate programs.