# How to set up a proxy server for a flurl client selectively?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, flurl

Is there a recommended way of defining a proxy for flurl clients based on the URL (or base URL)? I could not find anything in the documentation and discussions of the topic I did find (such as [Setting a per-request proxy (or rotating proxies) with .NET Flurl/HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52708836/setting-a-per-request-proxy-or-rotating-proxies-with-net-flurl-httpclient)) focuses on somewhat more complicated cases and [How can I use proxies for web requests in Flurl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50649348/how-can-i-use-proxies-for-web-requests-in-flurl) seems to set up the setting that would affect all calls (unless I misunderstood it).

In our scenario, an app calls different endpoints (other apps). Some of these endpoints can only be reached via a proxy server, some can be reached directly. Also, in some environments (DEV vs. PREPROD vs PROD), the same endpoints may need or not need a proxy, so the configuration could be similar to:

DEV

- https://x.com/endpoint1 (no proxy)
- https://y.com/endpoint2 (no proxy)
- https://z.com/endpoint3 (no proxy)

PREPROD

- https://x.com/endpoint1 (proxy A)
- https://y.com/endpoint2 (proxy B)
- https://z.com/endpoint3 (no proxy)

PROD

- https://x.com/endpoint1 (proxy A)
- https://y.com/endpoint2 (proxy B)
- https://z.com/endpoint3 (proxy A)

In this scenario, I assume that we need three HTTP clients (X, Y, and Z). What would be the right way to configure proxy settings for these clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating a new `HttpClient` factory that accepts a proxy address as described [here](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/228), but rather than registering it globally, create a `FlurlClientFactory` as described [here](https://flurl.dev/docs/configuration/#flurlclientfactory) that overrides `FlurlClientFactoryBase` and uses the proxy address at the cache key, guaranteeing exactly 1 `FlurlClient` per proxy.

```
public class ProxyFlurlClientFactory : FlurlClientFactoryBase
{
    protected override string GetCacheKey(Url url) => GetProxyForUrl(Url url);

    // Guaranteed to be called only once per proxy
    protected override IFlurlClient Create(Url url) {
        var httpFac = new ProxyHttpClientFactory(GetProxyForUrl(Url url));
        return new FlurlClient().Configure(settings => settings.HttpClientFactory = httpFac));
    }
    
    private string GetProxyForUrl(Url url) => ???; // whatever your rules are to pick the right one
}
```

This can be registered globally:

```
FlurlHttp.Configure(settings => settings.FlurlClientFactory = new ProxyFlurlClientFactory());
```

Or inject it via the [DI pattern](https://flurl.dev/docs/client-lifetime/#using-flurl-with-an-ioc-container) if you prefer.